# How to create a file already with content in android using commands?

Tags: java, android

**Hello everyone**

My problem is that I have to be able to create a file with the contents of an `Inputstream` using only commands, because the file will be created in the `/ data / data` directory, but not from my other applications application, and perform. This should be with `SuperUser` permissions and the problem is that to make `SuperUsuario` movements you need to use commands.

My current attempts are to place those files in writing and reading using the chmod command

```
Process proc3 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su -c chmod 777 /data/data/File.txt");
```

But he is not granted writing permission because the reading already has it.

If you know of any way to achieve my goal, please let me know. Thank you

Comment: What does "using only commands" mean?

Comment: The reason is that to be able to perform SuperUsuario movements you need commands, that is, to make a move I must declare the command `su` and with that I grant the permission of SuperUser and how I should continue to expand it, that is, I add more content to that command . An example is: `su -c touch /data/ data/file` will create a file in that directory but if I use the File class with the newfile method it will give me an error because it does not have permission to write to that directory. This is what I understand that I do not know if I am wrong or correct. Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "superuser movements"? And why do you need to create files directly in /data/data?

Comment: What I mean by movements is the ability to create, modify, edit, move everything you want from the system, which prevents programmers from doing this are limits that sets in default system and with the permission of Super User I can break those limits. And the reason I want to create a file in / data / data is that I want my application birnde to users the possibility of being able to make edits to the data that is saved, create new data or erase data. Thank you

Comment: most apps store data in internal or external storage. Internal storage is in /data/data/com.your.package and can be accessed directly with Java APIs.

Comment: Similarly, external storage is accessible with the Android API after your app requests the correct permission.

Comment: But as I mentioned will not be the data of my application therefore I can not even write a file in another folder other than mine. Thank you.

Comment: are you seeing that you want to write to files which belong to other apps?

Comment: One could say, Yes.